# How to display a header menu onclick containing two radio buttons working exclusively

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I created this button in my header, which normally displays a menu containing two vertically aligned radio buttons.
The problem is that the menu displays but the radiobuttons aren't exclusive and still checked even if i click on another.
My question is to how to define properly radio groups in a menu ?

Here's my code :

```
    Ext.define('Mine.view.headerThemeButton', {
        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

        xtype: 'headerThemeButton',
        width: 50,
        height: 58,
        padding : 'auto 0 auto 0',
        bodyStyle: 'border-color: #FFFFFF !important;',
 
        items: [{
            xtype:'button',
            height: '100%',
            glyph: 'xf142@FontAwesome',
            cls :'headerButtonsCls',
            listeners: {
                click: function(e,target) {
                    var coords = e.getXY(),
                        x = parseInt(coords[0]),
                        y = parseInt(coords[1]),
                        finalY = y + 50;

                    Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu',{
                        xtype: 'radiogroup',
                        columns: 1,
                        fieldLabel: 'Filmed In',
                        name: 'filmed_in',
                        items: [{
                            name: 'filmed_in',
                            boxLabel: 'Color',
                            inputValue: 'color'
                        },{
                            name: 'filmed_in',
                            boxLabel: 'Black & White',
                            inputValue: 'B&W'
                        }]
                    }).showAt(x, finalY);
                }
            }
        }]
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Inside the onClick created Menu, you set the xtype of the menu to radiogroup. But you have to add the radiogroup as an item.

```
Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
    // you missed this line
    items: [{
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        items: [
            //radiofields
        ]
     }]
  }).showAt(x, finalY);
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3abc)

Comment: Actually your solution still has a problem when i add a handler to each of the xtype radio elements : they are not exclusive !

Comment: You can easily read the value and use a single handler.